# content inside mat-card isn't centred using flex

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

i'm using angular materials to show a card, 
i want the content inside the card to be centred horizontal, 
even if i add `justify-content: flex-start; it doesn't make the content inside the card horizontal to one another, it always sticks to the left

here is my HTML

```
<!-- Classes main-div and example-card are categorised in .css file -->
<div class="main-div">
  <mat-card class="example-card">
    <mat-card-header>
      <div class="login-box-header">
          <!-- Src image is temporary hosted in image.ibb-->
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hDqa3p/codershood.png">
      </div>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <form>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" required>
              </mat-form-field>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password"type="password" name="password" required>
          </mat-form-field></td>
        </tr></table>
      </form>
      <mat-spinner [style.display]="showSpinner ? 'block' : 'none'"></mat-spinner>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="login()" color="primary">Login</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>

</div>
```

and here is my CSS file:

```
.example-card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main-div{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

i'm using angular materials, in angular.

how can i centre the content Inside the card ?

Thank you

Comment: can you please create a small angular app on https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
.example-card * {
  align-self: center;
}
```

:)

Comment: doesn't help i tried it it still aligned to the left

Comment: Strange. For me it's working. Did you add a new css rule with the " * " ?

Comment: basically align-items aligns the child element. align-self aligns the element it self. You have already centered the child but not the inner childs. so this way all the childs aligns them selfs in the center